# Is the Kawasaki disease related to COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19

Could this child syndrome  have a link to COVID-19?

Can we find any research that shows evidence?

https://www.cnbc.com/2020/04/28/coronavirus-may-cause-new-inflammatory-disease-in-children-medics-say.html

*It’s a new disease that we think may be caused by the COVID-19 virus — we’re not 100% sure because some of the people who got it hadn’t tested positive, so we’re doing a lot of research now but it is something we’re worried about. Although it is very significant for those children who do get it, the number of cases is small.”*

He also says: *It’s an absolutely tiny number*! I think the number of infected children is tiny anyway.

Comment: Wikipedia [answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawasaki_disease) your question. And since Kawasaki disease was identified almost 60 years before the SARS-CoV-2 virus even existed, I think we can safely say there's no connection.

Comment: Some other coronaviruses have been linked to Kawasaki Disease.

Comment: @Carey: *Kawasaki disease can be diagnosed only clinically (i.e., by medical signs and symptoms). No specific laboratory test exists for this condition.* This wiki has been written before the SARS-2 virus could have been tested. My question is pointing whether it has to be rewritten.

Comment: My point is that your question demonstrates zero prior research. If I can google your question and find an answer immediately, then your question needs work. This is a poor question.

Comment: The CNBC report linked states that the new inflammatory disease is **likened to Kawasaki disease and sepsis**, not that it **is** Kawasaki disease or sepsis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The causes of [Kawasaki disease/syndrome](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/kawasaki-disease/symptoms-causes/syc-20354598) are not well understood.

Kawasaki involves inflammation of blood vessels, and is rare but almost exclusively found in young children.

There are [media reports](https://www.cnn.com/2020/04/27/health/children-covid-19-illness-intl-scli-gbr/index.html) of associations of Kawasaki and COVID-19 but these are fairly early reports and it is unlikely (and I am unaware of any) that there are any sufficiently large samples of cases that have been organized to suggest a true causal role: these alerts are best directed towards physicians to be aware of the possibility when examining patients rather than to the general public.

Comment: There have also been reports of some kind of [rare] inflammatory reaction to Covid-19 in children. I have no idea if they could be related but Kawasaki's disease has been mentioned in such contexts/discussion. https://www.cnbc.com/2020/04/28/coronavirus-may-cause-new-inflammatory-disease-in-children-medics-say.html (I see you CNN link is actually about the same thing, i.e. the alert from the England NHS on children with this presentation.)

Comment: * It’s a new disease that we think may be caused by the Covid-19 virus — we’re not 100% sure because some of the people who got it hadn’t tested positive, so we’re doing a lot of research now but it is something we’re worried about. Although it is very significant for those children who do get it, the number of cases is small.”* he also says: It’s an absolutely tiny number*! I think the number of infected children is tiny anyway.

Comment: @Fizz - the CNBC report you linked states that the new inflammatory disease is **likened to Kawasaki disease and sepsis**, not that it **is** Kawasaki disease or sepsis.